# Make a model go to a desired place by going one by one in waypoints

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

So I'm trying to make a game with a car cutscene where the car drives up to a house in waypoints, similar to pathfinding

[[image: 1]

So it goes to point 1, stops, and then goes to point 2 and ends, but not in a straight line, so it goes to the parts that are in a folder like waypoints that are placed or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more waypoints, so each path from waypoint to waypoint is a straight line, and traverse it using a for loop or other iteration methods, you can choose between lerping, tweening or anything. Though lerping might be the smoothest without cuts inbetween waypoints.

Code could be

```lua
local car = ...
local waypoints = {...}

local _maxValue = 100 -- over how much iterations it should take to reach the next waypoint

for _, waypoint in ipairs(waypoints) do
    for i=1, _maxValue do
        car:PivotTo(car:GetPivot():Lerp(CFrame.new(waypoint.Position), i/_maxValue))
    end
end
```

In reality, you might want to tweak the code to ensure the car won't rotate in weird directions all of a sudden.

Comment: I used chatgpt to do it but its kind of the same as that told me to do while my uses tweeningservice but thank you very much i forgot to close the question and i just remembered about it rn ill mark yours as correct bcuz i bet it will also work as i look at it.